# Difference b/w std::vector<int> V(N) and std::vector<int> V[N]?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Are these 2 statements `std::vector<int> V(N)` and `std::vector<int> V[N]` equivalent??

Also what do they mean?

Comment: The first is a vector that has N elements pre-allocated.  The latter is an array of N empty vectors.

Comment: Let me ask you: What's the difference between `int foo(42)` and `int foo[42]`?

Comment: @Eljay does that mean the second statement is a kind of a 2D array??

Comment: it means the second statement should probably rather be `std::array<std::vector<int>,N>`, but thats not the best way to represent a 2d array to begin with. `std::vector<int> V[N]` is abundant in low quality tutorials and strange competition code, it might have some real uses, but I have never seen it elsewhere

Comment: Yes, the second statement is a kind of 2D array.  A bizarre one.  Much like a lion-goat-snake Chimera is a kind of bizarre serpentine (or bizarre leonine, or bizarre caprine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector<int> V(N)` creates an `std::vector<int>` of size `N`.

`std::vector<int> V[N]` creates an **array** of size `N` **containing** `std::vector<int>`.

You can see this from this piece of code :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
const int N = 100;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> test(N);
    std::cout << test.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(test[0]).name() << '\n'; //output i

    int i=1; test[0] = i;  //runs fine
    //std::vector<int> i2; test[0] = i2; //converting error

    std::vector<int> test2[N];
    std::cout << sizeof(test2)/sizeof(test2[0]) << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(test2[0]).name();

    //int i3=1; test2[0] = i3; //converting error
    std::vector<int> i4; test2[0] = i4; //runs fine
}
```

Result:

```
100
i
100
St6vectorIiSaIiEE
```

Edit: As @463035818_is_not_a_number and @Eljay mentioned, `std::vector<int> V[N]` should be written as `std::array<std::vector<int>,N>` for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question comes in two parts. The first concerns basic syntax, and the second concerns semantics for the `std::vector` container. One of them is built into the language itself, the other is declared as part of the standard library.

Part 1:

> Are these 2 statements std::vector V(N) and std::vector V[N] equivalent??

No. It appears you're confusing built-in array declaration syntax (i.e. the `[]` brackets), with the "array-like" semantics of the library-declared `std::vector<T>` object. It might help to recognize that under the hood, `std::vector<T>` is going to be declared as a `struct` or `class`. In a very rough sense, it will look something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct vector {
    vector();
    vector(size_type count);
    ...
    T *storage;
    size_type count;
};
```

Here you see it will have a few different constructors, including one that takes a `size_type` and pre-allocates memory to store enough elements. A full list of the available constructors for `std::vector` can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

The `()` syntax in your example is a call to a *constructor*, the behavior of which is implementation defined. The square bracket `[]` declaration syntax is a language feature that tells the *compiler* to allocate that many objects either on the stack or on the heap, depending on where the allocation occurs.

In most cases (I won't say never because there are always exceptions), you're not going to use `std::vector<int> V[N]` because `std::vector<int> V` is already a way to store an "array" of elements.